# How to insert a character inside the values of the select query

Tags: mysql, select, insert

This is my sample select query:

```
SELECT item from tbl
```

And this is the result:

```
1001
2001
```

Is there a function in MySQL that I can insert characters to the value in my select query? Like this one:

```
1-001
2-002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [INSERT() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_insert). Your code should look something like this:

```
SELECT INSERT(item, ,2, 0, '-') item from tbl
```

Comment: this is shorter then the CONCAT version as it is just one function call and not three

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', LEFT(item, 1), SUBSTRING(item, 2)) FROM tbl
```

Comment: Wow this solves my problem sir, very genius! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', LEFT(item, 1), SUBSTRING(item, 2)) FROM tbl
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac4c75/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT  
CONCAT(LEFT( `item ` , 1) ,'-' ,`item`)
FROM `tbl`
```

or

```
SELECT  
CONCAT(LEFT( `item ` , 1) ,'-' ,SUBSTRING(`item`,2)
FROM `tbl`
```

Comment: This would give `1-1001`

Comment: @Phil i didn't break column value in first solution missed that part

Answer (score -2):

**syntax** will be:

```
INSERT (ori_string, in_pos, length, new_string)
```